# Error while deploying a Qt application on Fedora 19

Tags: mysql, qt, deployment

I created an app that uses Qt **Gui**, **Core**, **Network** and **Sql** ( **MySQL** ) libraries. Now I want to deploy it on Linux. This is the deploy directory structure :
**|-chatbox ( binary file )

|-libQtCore.so.4

|-libQtCore.so.4.8.5

|-libQtGui.so.4

|-libQtGui.so.4.8.5

|-libQtNetwork.so.4

|-libQtNetwork.so.4.8.5

|-libQtSql.so.4

|-libQtSql.so.4.8.5

|-sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so

|-chatbox.sh**

chatbox.sh following to instructions in Qt's website contains this code :

```
#!/bin/sh
 appname=`basename $0 | sed s,\.sh$,,`

 dirname=`dirname $0`
 tmp="${dirname#?}"

 if [ "${dirname%$tmp}" != "/" ]; then
 dirname=$PWD/$dirname
 fi
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$dirname
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 $dirname/$appname "$@"
```

But when my boss runs this script in a system without Qt installed, encounters this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries libqtsql.so.4 file is too short
```

So is my directory structure true? Are these libraries and SQL plugin enough to run? And what's the mentioned error?

Comment: "file is too short"? Looks like a corrupt file. Are you sure libqtsql.so.4 is actually a (valid) shared object file?

Comment: @Mat : I'm unfortunately a Windows user. Is it possible to find out whether it's corrupted ? Can he install Qt libraries from repositories?

Comment: Just look at its size, and check the file against wherever it is you got that file from.

Comment: Compare md5 sums for a complete check. Here file size should suffice though.

Comment: @Mat: Yeah thank you. The problem now is that MySql driver couldn't be loaded!In Windows I place it in `sqldrivers` folder.